# Is is possible to filter on an OData navigation property?

Tags: filtering, odata

A USERS collection contains a USERGROUPS navigation property.

Users are accessed through `/api/Users?$expand=USERGROUPS`.

USERGROUPS navigation property contains ID, and I would like to filter by UserGroups.Id by something like:

`/api/Users?$expand=USERGROUPS&$filter=startswith(USERGROUPS/ID,'a')`

Ultimately I'd like to be able to filter on a specific group ID value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually OData V3 supports something like that with the any/all operator. So for example if you want to search for all users which belong to user group with id 'a' the query would look something like:

```
/api/Users?$filter=USERGROUPS/any(usergroup: usergroup/ID eq 'a')
```

Note though, that the feature is only supported in OData V3, so you need to enable that on the server.

Comment: Since my stack is MVC, WebAPI, OData, will this do what I need:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nivot.WCFDataServicesToolkit/ ?  I have the OData -pre Nuget installation.

Comment: The syntax you gave doesn't include the $expand=USERGROUPS option.  Isn't that needed to add the USERGROUPS navigation property?

Comment: Actually in trying that syntax now, it works perfectly - exactly what I was looking for.  Still getting the hang of the OData syntax & thank you.

Comment: I didn't include the $expand since you don't need that for the filter to work, but if you want to get the expanded entity onto the client, then include it, it should work just fine with or without it.

Comment: Makes sense.  Any thoughts on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130813/why-are-there-missing-client-side-results-when-using-odata-options-with-entity-f

Answer (score 0):

**-- EDITED --**

Initially, I believe I found my answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e15f0c02-1df1-4bce-8204-1dd63a026403/how-to-write-a-referencial-query-using-odata):

> OData doesn't support filter on navigation properties who are
>   collections

Since in my data set, UserGroups is a collection, it will not be possible to perform a filter on this property.

**HOWEVER** - with the syntax given above, and the use of OData v3, this works perfectly well!