# Why are there missing client-side results when using OData options with Entity Framework DBContext?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-5, odata

OData and Entity Framework are suppose to work well together, in that OData options will be passed to the EF db context to filter queries - ie. return only the number of records requested from the server as not to inflate the payload rather than all the records then filter.

Given the following URL path:

```
/api/Users?$top=10&$skip=10
```

Given the following controller action:

```
    [Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    public IEnumerable<USER> Get(ODataQueryOptions<USER> options)
    {
        var dbContext = new ATMS.DAL.AtmsContext();
        //var ret = options.ApplyTo(dbContext.USERS).Cast<USER>().ToArray();        // returns 10 rows but client sees 0
        var ret = dbContext.USERS.ToArray();                                        // returns all records, filtered results to client

        return ret;
    }
```

When using `ret = options.ApplyTo(dbContext.USERS).Cast<USER>().ToArray();`, from SQL Server Profiler I see that the appropriate query is executed and 10 results are returned from the db through Entity Framework.

An array of 10 items is returned by `ret` however the problem is that no data is included in the response to the client:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:59337/api/$metadata#Users","value":[

  ]
}
```

When no skip is specified, the top 10 results are returned - obviously not useful for paging.

When using `ret = dbContext.USERS.ToArray();` the top 10 results and skip are properly applied, but only because **ALL** of the results are returned from the database, and filtering applied thereafter, which is not what I am trying to achieve.

In my WebApiConfig.cs I have `config.EnableQuerySupport();`.

Adding a `PageSize` attribute has no effect:

```
[Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All, PageSize = 10)]
```

Returning `IQueryable<User>` also has no effect.

Returning `PageResult<USER>` - no change:

```
    IQueryable results = options.ApplyTo(dbContext.USERS.AsQueryable(), settings);

    return new PageResult<USER>(
        results as IEnumerable<USER>,
        Request.GetNextPageLink(),
        Request.GetInlineCount());
```

-- More Info --

Using `/api/Users?$top=10&$skip=0`, if I set a breakpoint at the beginning of the action method and while debugging in Visual Studio I set the Skip.RawValue, and continue execution, I get the 10 results expected:

[image: Manually edited Skip values]

It appears that somehow the results are being subject to an additional skip, which may be why no results are displayed.

**When `http://localhost:59337/api/Users?$top=10&$skip=9` is used, the second-last result of page 2 is displayed - only one result.**

What am I missing to get this working properly, and has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mix and match `QueryableAttribute` and `ODataQueryOptions<T>`. Pick one depending on whether you want manual control over applying the query options (`ODataQueryOptions<T>`) or make it happen automatically (`QueryableAttribute`).

You have two options,

```
public IEnumerable<USER> Get(ODataQueryOptions<USER> options)
{
    var dbContext = new ATMS.DAL.AtmsContext();
    var ret = options.ApplyTo(dbContext.USERS).Cast<USER>();
    return ret;
}
```

or

```
[Queryable]
public IEnumerable<USER> Get(ODataQueryOptions<USER> options)
{
    var dbContext = new ATMS.DAL.AtmsContext();
    var ret = dbContext.USERS;
    return ret;
}
```

The reason you are seeing that behavior is that you are applying the query twice, once using `ODataQueryOptions<T>.ApplyTo` and then again through `QueryableAttribute`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, as that was my suspicion that the query was being applied a second time.  Thank you.